# Multiply a set of values across a dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID    A  B  C
1    .3 .3 .4
2    .1 .5 .4
3    .7  0 .3
```

And I have the following:

```
ID  VALUE
1      10
1       5
1     100
2      30
3      34
2      12
```

I basically want to multiply my `VALUE` across my `Df1` to produce those variables. So for each instance of the ID, the appropriate multipliers are used. Dplyr solution is needed here.

My final goal:

```
ID  VALUE     A   B     C
1      10     3   3     4
1       5   1.5 1.5     2 
1     100    30  30    40
2      30     3  15    12
3      34  23.8   0  10.2
2      12   1.2   6   4.8
```

EDIT: The ID variable is a character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is the merge the two by `ID` then multiply across those variables you want.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~ID,    ~A,  ~B,  ~C,
  1,  .3, .3, .4,
  2,   .1, .5, .4,
  3,    .7,  0, .3
)

df2 <- tribble(
  ~ID,  ~VALUE,
  1,      10,
  1,       5,
  1,     100,
  2,      30,
  3,      34,
  2,      12
)

left_join(
  df2, df1, by = "ID"
) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(A, B, C), ~VALUE*.)


# A tibble: 6 x 5
     ID VALUE     A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10   3     3     4  
2     1     5   1.5   1.5   2  
3     1   100  30    30    40  
4     2    30   3    15    12  
5     3    34  23.8   0    10.2
6     2    12   1.2   6     4.8
```

**EDIT**:

To mutate all variables at once, replace the last chunk of code for:

```
left_join(
  df2, df1, by = "ID"
) %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(ID, VALUE), ~VALUE*.x))
```

Comment: Note that `mutate_at()` and other scoped verbs are being superseded in `dplyr`. The recommended use is `mutate` + `across`, as in `mutate(across(c(A, B, C), ~ VALUE * .x))`

Comment: Okay this is close; my data however is about 100 variables, so more than A,B, and C.

Comment: @JoaoPedroMacalos thanks for the fyi, was not aware

Comment: @JohnThomas you could use tidy selection for those 100 variables. or another solution would involve some long/wide transform to make the operation simpler

Comment: @JoaoPedroMacalos this almost works, but everything() still includes the ID variable which is a character so it doesn't work. Basically it needs to work on every variable EXCEPT ID, first column and only character var

Comment: My mistake. Try `mutate(across(-c(ID, VALUE), ~VALUE*.x))`

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do:

```
n <- ncol(df1)
A <- merge(df1, df2[c(1, rep(2, n-1))])
A[2:n] * A[(2:n) + n - 1]
     A    B    C
1  3.0  3.0  4.0
2  1.5  1.5  2.0
3 30.0 30.0 40.0
4  3.0 15.0 12.0
5  1.2  6.0  4.8
6 23.8  0.0 10.2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(df1)[-1]
setDT(df2)[setDT(df1), (nm1) := lapply(mget(paste0("i.", nm1)),
             `*`, VALUE),on = .(ID)]
```

-output

```
df2
#   ID VALUE    A    B    C
#1:  1    10  3.0  3.0  4.0
#2:  1     5  1.5  1.5  2.0
#3:  1   100 30.0 30.0 40.0
#4:  2    30  3.0 15.0 12.0
#5:  3    34 23.8  0.0 10.2
#6:  2    12  1.2  6.0  4.8
```